# How can I modify(add/delete resource paths) a running uWebSockets server?

Tags: webserver, uwebsockets, usocket

I have implemented a simple uWebsockets server that is listening on a certain port. Lets say I have added some resource paths to the Webserver(ex: /test1, /test2) so the server is listening and a client can send request to those resource paths.

Now imagine I need to add a third resource path (/test3) to the above server. What kind of strategy should I follow to do that? Because as I can see that server itself is a loop.

It is better if I can get an answer related to uWebSockets, but otherwise it is okay to explain in a general webserver manner.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Register a catch-all handler ("/*"), and do the routing yourself
- I presume you can terminate the App (have it exit), and start a new one with the extra paths.